# How can you implement two way pegged Ethereum <-> Ethereum sidechain?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, sidechain, two-way-pegged

If you want to create an Ethereum sidechain which is two-way pegged to main (public or private) Ethereum, how can you implement sidechain?

For example,

- How can you lock ether?
- How can you verify main net ether?

Comment: Would be nice to merge this with: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/562/whats-involved-in-making-a-private-chain-become-a-sidechain-of-ethereum?rq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Locking and releasing ether is very simple. The biggest problem is that you need to verify the ethash proof of work if you want a real trustless connection. It is probably not feasible to perform this verification on the blockchain alone, but there are plans on how to do it [interactively](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/02/17/smart-contracts-courts-not-smart-judges/).

For interactive verification, you either have to implement ethash in Solidity/EVM in a step-wise manner where only one step will be executed in the worst case, or you take the official C implementation, compile it to a simple architecture ([lanai](http://reviews.llvm.org/D17011) seems to be the most promising currently) and implement this architecture in Solidity/EVM. In both cases, you have to augment the native implementation with Merkle-hashing the memory as explained in the article above.