# Sidechain with Ethereum

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, sidechain

can any one please suggest me how to implement side  block chain for Ethereum. I heard about doge coin but have not found anything related to it.
Thanks
Amit Modi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could try to look at [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/379/what-is-a-sidechain), it explains what a sidechain is

  - Doge coin is not a side chain nor related to Ethereum
  - I think you should try to explain more precisely what you are looking for and do a lot more research before asking a question
  - You might be looking for [ERC20 token](https://etherscan.io/tokens) (google it), or maybe you meant [ethereum sharding](https://medium.com/@icebearhww/ethereum-sharding-and-finality-65248951f649) (shard chains)

Hope I was helpful, have a nice day.