# Communicating between a Sidechain and a Mainchain

Tags: addresses, address.transfer, sidechain

Side chains ([see linked question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/379/what-is-a-sidechain) ) can be seen as a blockchain attached to a "parent" blockchain using a "two way" peg.  Smart contract addresses are generated deterministically(HD wallet style), but the wallet style addressing is for smart contracts.

Unlike smart contract addressing, when the Parent blockchain addresses the 
side chain(or vice versa) are there addressing issues like making deterministic wallet style addresses for the chains(a main chain could make a wallet style address for a sidechain), or communicating between the two blockchains(Parent and Sidechain), or is done using network addressing via sockets(and so on..)?

Answer (score 1):

A sidechain can communicate with the mainchain by use of ethereum bridges. This technique can be seen as an effective means of communication a sidechain and mainchain.

Comment: This answer would be better if you included a description of what an ethereum bridge is, how they work, resource links to theory/explainers and implementations.